# File size is double while replacing value in variable and output with a different name

Tags: powershell

When replacing a value from a base text, and outputting the file, the file size double, rather than 4kb to 8kb.

```
$t=3
$F=30
Do{
$t = $t+1
$F=$F+10
$y = (Get-Content -Path D:\test.php).Replace("YU9","$F")
$y | Out-File D:\Test\delivery$t.php -Force

}
until($t -eq 50)
```

Comment: `... | Out-File D:\Test\delivery$t.php -Force -Encoding utf8`

Comment: Great it works, -Encoding utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, powershell 5.1 out-file defaults to utf16 or unicode, so it's twice as big as ascii or utf8.  Unicode has nulls inbetween each letter.  The first two bytes are the BOM.  "0D 0A" is carriage return and linefeed.

```
'abcde' | set-content file
'abcde' | out-file file2

format-hex file


           Path: C:\Users\js\foo\file

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   61 62 63 64 65 0D 0A                             abcde..


format-hex file2


           Path: C:\Users\js\foo\file2

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF FE 61 00 62 00 63 00 64 00 65 00 0D 00 0A 00  .þa.b.c.d.e.....
```